# Function "struct2table" ascii output

Tags: matlab, struct, ascii

I am using the function "struct2table" in order to print the fields of a MatLab structure into a table. 
Nevertheless, when I use this function I do have an output but just directly printed in the command window. Does anyone has any idea about how to print the output in an ascii files that can be open outside MatLab? 
For example, I have the structure "s":

```
field = 'f';
value = {'some text';
         [10, 20, 30];
         magic(5)};
s = struct(field,value)
```

I want to get an ascii output of this table using "struct2table" function. How can I get this ascii output, and not only in appearing in the command window.Thank you!

Comment: See: [`writetable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)

Comment: @excaza - Thank you! But the fact is that when you use the 'struct2table' function you cannot write the output in the workspace (the function crash by too many argument when asking ´T = struct2table(report))´. Therefore I cannot use writetable!

Comment: That is a separate issue and one we cannot help you with until you provide us [a minimal, functioning example that reproduces your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not encounter any errors using `struct2table` with the sample data provided.

Comment: @excaza - Maybe my question is not clear enough. I don´t have any problem while running struct2table function. My issue, is that the output is directly printed in the command window, my wish is to get this output as an "ascii" file that can be forwarded and useable outside matlab.

Comment: I told you how to do that, `writetable`. Then you said you got an error with `struct2table` so you can't use `writetable`. Now you're saying you don't have a problem with `struct2table`. What is your actual issue?

Comment: @excaza - I can´t use "writetable", because you need to have your input in your workspace, and struct2table does not print anything in your workspace (just in the command window), am I right? Moreover, my MatLab version is too old to use "writetable".

Comment: Like all other functions with outputs, you have to declare `struct2table` with an output variable to store it in your workspace. What version of MATLAB do you have? How do you have `struct2table` and not `writetable`? They were both introduced in R2013b with the `table` datatype.

Comment: @excaza - I have downloaded struct2table on the MatLab file exchange (writetable is not available there). As I told you before you cannot declare any workspace output by using struct2table function (you will get the error message "too many input argument". Therefore, I am currently trying to change the struct2table function (using fprintf and fopen) in order to get an useable output.

Comment: That you're not using builtin functions would have been a great piece of information to provide in your problem statement...

Comment: @excaza - I am sorry I had no idea that struct2table is now a MatLab built in function, My fault!

Comment: Now I'm much less confused. You may be able to use `struct2array` or `struct2cell`, but where to go from there (or whether those are even the best option) depends on your data format and desired output format.

Comment: @excaza - Thanks a lot for your help! I will have a look to these functions